# How to re-order divs with jquery from a,a,b,b to a,b,a,b?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

First, I have to say that I haven't tried anything yet since I have no idea how to do it.
I also searched but I didn't find any solutions.

I'd like to re-order DIVs with jquery from the following

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="A1"></div>
   <div class="A2"></div>
   <div class="B1"></div>
   <div class="B2"></div>
...and so on...
</div>
```

to this

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="A1"></div>
    <div class="B1"></div>
    <div class="A2"></div>
    <div class="B2"></div>
...and so on...
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you want to do with this ?

Comment: Be more specific, are there always two elements, followed by two elements etc. and what element should move where etc. or doesn't it really matter?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not specific.
I already updated the questions.
Yes, it will be two by two forever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's another way to do it, without incrementing an index

```
$('.A + .B').each(function() {
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5TRqF/2/)

Comment: You may want to fix the fiddle :p

Comment: @Adrift - Gee, where did that come from? Was probably using an old Fiddle and forgot to save it ?

Comment: Will only work as long as there is only 4 items as in the question, or if the A's and B's come in pairs. @techfoobar's solution will work with three or more A's in a row. Who knows what OP wants though

Comment: @techfoobar - we were thinking the same thing, so they are very similar. I just thought I would have to check for a `.B` coming after an `.A` to be able to move it up etc, but for the given example with just four elements evenly spaced it wouldn't really matter, but getting it that way it's easier to just insert it back too.

Comment: @xec - That was the point. I understood it as moving one element up to get alternating classes etc. If it's just a matter of getting any collection of elements to alternate classes, techfoobar's answer should work.

Comment: I marked this as an answer since the code works fine and is cleaner.

But may I ask a stupid question? What does the plus sign mean?

Thanks,

Comment: It is the sibling combinator http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/adjacent-sibling-selector-css-selector/

Comment: @AtthaponJunpun-eak - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Comment: ^^^ Yup, sibling selector, it will only select a `.B` element that comes after an `.A` element

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to reorder the elements:

```
var aIndex = 0;
$('.B').each(function() {
    $(this).insertAfter('.A:eq('+(aIndex++)+')');
});
```

**[Demo of the above](http://jsfiddle.net/wxYss/)**

This assumes that you have the same number of A's and B's in there.

Comment: I voted this up to since this also works fine but the code is not as clean as @adeneo.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7GFrs/)</kbd>

[.after( function(index) )](http://api.jquery.com/after/#after-functionindex)

```
$('.A').after(function (i) {
    return $('.B:eq(' + i + ')')
});
```

---

Will balance all elements with class `.A` till we have elements with class `B` .

[Fiddle 2 more element with B class](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7GFrs/2/)

[Fiddle 2 more element with A class](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7GFrs/3/)

Comment: @techfoobar ty i have added more fiddles might help .

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.wrapper .B').each(function(i,el){
        $(this).insertAfter('.wrapper .A:eq('+i+')');
    });
});
```

See docs for [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) and [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code if you equal number of A and B elemnets

```
$('document').ready(function(){    
    var aIndex = 0;    

    $('#wrapper .B').each(function(idx,element) {    
        $(this).insertAfter('.A:eq('+(idx)+')');
    });
});
```